# Getting polyfill "vminpoly" working with internal CSS

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-7, polyfills, viewport-units

On Saabi's github for vminpoly, a vw and vh unit polyfill (https://github.com/saabi/vminpoly), it says:

> Only linked stylesheets are being parsed right now but it's very easy
> to also parse 'style' elements.

How would vw and vh CSS inside style elements work with vminpoly?

Comment: Do you need to polyfill `vw`, `vh` in inside style elements? I didn't find the way to do this with vminpoly. Which version of browser are you using? I think the best way is to wirte the css styles in linked stylesheets then use vminpoly.

Comment: Plolyfilling only vw in particular (for font-size on desktop widths only). Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8, whatever works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could refer to the code below to support `vh`, `vw` in particular:

```js
(function($, window) {

  var $win = $(window),
    _css = $.fn.css;

  function viewportToPixel(val) {
    var percent = val.match(/\d+/)[0] / 100,
      unit = val.match(/[vwh]+/)[0];
    return (unit == 'vh' ? $win.height() : $win.width()) * percent + 'px';
  }

  function parseProps(props) {
    var p, prop;
    for (p in props) {
      prop = props[p];
      if (/[vwh]$/.test(prop)) {
        props[p] = viewportToPixel(prop);
      }
    }
    return props;
  }

  $.fn.css = function(props) {
    var self = this,
      update = function() {
        return _css.call(self, parseProps($.extend({}, props)));
      };
    $win.resize(update);
    return update();
  };

}(jQuery, window));

//Usage:
$('div').css({
  height: '50vh',
  width: '50vw',
  marginTop: '25vh',
  marginLeft: '25vw',
  fontSize: '10vw'
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background: #fa7098;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>hello</div>
```

The result in IE is like this:

[image]

Comment: This is a valid replacement for for me instead of vminpoly. Thanks.